# Hypergeometric confluent function divergence with scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I have a problem with the hypergeometric confluent function of scipy.
The code is

```
from scipy import special

print special.hyp1f1(-0.5, 0.5, -705)
print special.hyp1f1(-0.5, 0.5, -706)
```

and I obtain the output

```
47.0619041347
inf
```

I don't understand why the function is divergent. The hypergeometric confluent function has an asymptotic expansion for large x, and there shouldn't be any pole for these values of the parameters. Am I wrong, or this is a bug? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: For the `(a,b) = (-0.5, 0.5)` case you can write it in terms of `erf`; that should work over a very wide range without overflow.

Comment: I'm not completely sure. According to [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Special_cases), the erf function is obtained for (a,b) = (0.5,1.5)

Comment: @user2983686: no, I didn't mean that it *was* erf, I meant you could write it in *terms of* erf.

Comment: @DSM: oh, I misunderstood your words, I'm sorry. I'll try to follow your suggestion! It is also possible to solve the problem by using mpmath, as explained in the link provided by alko!

Comment: `mpmath` is my favourite arbitrary-precision special function library too.  :^)  I haven't had enough coffee to do arithmetic yet, but I think it's something like `I*sqrt(pi)*sqrt(x)*erf(I*sqrt(x)) + exp(x)`.

Comment: Great, now I'm going to check it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A (known) bug: [scipy.special.hyp1f1(0.5, 1.5, -1000) fails.](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2282)

See also pull request [hyp1f1: better handling of large negative arguments](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3022) for reasons (namely, exponent overflow).

Kummer's hypergeometric function has poles only in negative integers, so is well defined for your usecase.

Comment: Oh I see, very appreciated alko!

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI: you can use the excellent [mpmath library](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) to get a hyp1f1 function which does not have this issue. Without GMP/MPIR + gmpy2 installed the library will be a bit slower than the scipy function but you will have arbitrary precision available.

mpmath example:

```
In [19]: hyp1f1(-0.5, 0.5, -706)
Out[19]: mpf('47.1')

In [20]: mp.dps = 25

In [21]: hyp1f1(-0.5, 0.5, -706)
Out[21]: mpf('47.09526954413143632617966605')
```

### IMPORTANT NOTE

This scipy function will not always return inf when it can not handle the size of the return value. The values (-0.5, 0.5, 706) simply returns an incorrect answer.